# How to make the screenshot of the entire display containing the browser using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Does anybody know how to make full screenshot of display using webdriver?
In Selenium documentation I read that it is possible: (http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html)

..

The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser

..

I use Selenium Grid. My hub is on linux and node on windows. I tried to use Robot, however it takes screenshot on linux, however needs on windows

Comment: You need more information; there really isn't a question here.  For example, what have you tried?  Do you have any code that you have written?  If so, post it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a screenshot of your currently running browser instance then you can do it using following code:

```
  public static void captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String screenshotFileName)
    {
        String screenshotsFile = screenshotsFolder+screenshotFileName+imageExtention;

        try {
            File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(screenshotsFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

But if you want to take screenshot of your active window (other than browser only) then you can use Robot class.

**Edit:**

Although it's too late for you, the link below contains your answer. I think it may be helpful for others who are searching for the same thing.
[Screen shot issue in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844379/screen-shot-issue-in-selenium-webdriver/39847648#39847648)

Comment: Yes, I need to take screenshot of my active window. However my hub is on Linux and Nodes are on Windows. So Robot takes screenshot on linux

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **FirefoxDriver** to screenshot whole page.
Chrome and IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score -1):

hi try it like below it will take the complete webpage screen shot

```
 File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
 //The below method will save the screen shot in defined drive with name "screenshot.png"
 FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("yourPath\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to take screenshot of whole display.