# Selenium scrolling

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I want to take screenshots of all the related search results suggestions based on the keyword entered but one after another, ho do i do this in selenium??

```
    for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) { 
    //Import data for company names. 
    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1); 
    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING); 
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //Here i'm reading and writing inputs from excel sheet
    WebElement SearchBar = driver.findElement(By.className("search-global-typeahead__input"));
    SearchBar.sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue(), Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    SearchBar.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ashot Api in selenium to take entire page screenshot.

[How to take full page Screenshot of a scrollable webpage using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973508/how-to-take-full-page-screenshot-of-a-scrollable-webpage-using-selenium-webdrive) this link will help to resolve this

Comment: i dont want to take entire page screenshot, for ex i have entered some keyword into searchbar and the results or suggestion coming out i want to take screenshot of those suggestions but not at once but one after another

Comment: You can do this on ashot Api please try this (there is option to scroll screen)